# Enabling system-wide dynamic range compression

Tags: 10.04, sound, pulseaudio, 9.10

I need to enable dynamic range compression system wide. I've tried looking around some but couldn't find anything precise on how to set it up. The target system is running Ubuntu Karmic, but instructions for Lucid would be helpful as well if there's any difference. Command line steps would be preferred as I'd need to automate the process to run on many machines, which do not all share similar hardware. They're currently using pulseaudio.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: I could use an answer to this!